# jqplot x axis spacing

Tags: javascript, html, graph, jqplot, spacing

I am using jqplot and am having trouble with the spacing on the X axis.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var plot3 = $.jqplot('CogsLineGraph', [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [2,3,4,5,6,7], [3,4,5,6,7,8]], 
{ 
    title:'Cogs (Last 6 Months)', 
    seriesDefaults: 
    {
        rendererOptions: {smooth: true}
    },
    series:[ 
        {
            lineWidth:1, 
            markerOptions: { size:7, style:'dimaond' }
        }, 
        {
            lineWidth:1, 
            markerOptions: { size: 7, style:"dimaond" }
        }, 
        {
            lineWidth:1,  
            markerOptions: { size:7, style:"filledSquare" }
        }
        ]
    }
); 
});
```

Here is an image of the graph displayed on a web page:

[image]

On the X axis, the values are:

0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 etc

Can I please have some help to modify my code such that the values on the X axis are as follows:

0, 1, 2, 3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
axes: {
xaxis: {

    ticks: ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
       }
}
```